# How to use mergelocales.py for GWT across Multiple Projects

Tags: gwt, internationalization, gwt-platform

I have some projects:

- WebShared (Java Library project)
- WebExternal (GWT Web Application)
- WebInternal (GWT Web Application)

I have UI Binder's which are shared between WebExternal and WebInternal, and I organize those under the "WebShared" project.

I am now adding i18n support, and I want to use UI Binder's <ui:msg> tags, and consolidate them using the GWT-P mergelocales.py script.

Mergelocales.py works by running against a GWT app that was GWT compiled using the -extra parameter.  Since WebShared is not a GWT app, running the script against it produces no output.  Additionally, running mergelocales.py against WebExternal or WebInternal does not produce a file that includes the messages from the WebShared project.

I believe it would work if I converted the WebShared project into a GWT project, but then I would still have two separate properties files to send to the translation service, and I don't want to deal with combining files or managing multiple files.

What is the best way to handle this scenario using the available tools, OR do I need to create my own script?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

This actually works by default.  When the GWT Compiler runs, it generates .property files for the UI Binders that are localized, even if used from a dependent project, and the mergelocales.py script runs against those property files.